# Why is the shared pointer not going out of scope at end of main?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, circular-dependency

I have deliberately introduced a circular dependency in below code.

My doubt is that since when the shared pointer w goes out of scope, then the ref count is not zero and hence Widget object won't be destroyed.

But at the end of main, won't the shared pointer ' w->mGadget->mWidget' too go out of scope, since everything is known to cease to exist at the end of main? I am bit confused about the scope here. I was expecting that all entity scope should get over when main exits. Where is the missing link in my understanding here?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct Gadget;

struct Widget
{
    std::shared_ptr<Gadget> mGadget;
};

struct Gadget
{
    std::shared_ptr<Widget> mWidget;
};

int main()
{
    auto w = std::make_shared<Widget>();
    w->mGadget = std::make_shared<Gadget>();
    w->mGadget->mWidget = w;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They are in a reference loop with each other.

Comment: You might be mixing up scope with lifetime. Both shared pointers go out of scope, but do to the circular reference their life time does not end.

Comment: @TanveerBadar - if both go out of scope then the ref count should become zero. as a result no memory leak should occur. this is against shared pointer ref count logic. Can you be bit detailed as i am not understanding your point. i know i have added a circular dependency intentionally. C++ standard says if ref count reaches zero then object is destroyed.

Comment: There are two instances of `shared_ptr` referring to the same `Widget` object - `w` and `mWidget` member of `Gadget`. Only one of them is a local variable (formally, a variable with automatic storage duration) for which "goes out of scope" is a meaningful statement. `w` indeed goes out of scope at the end of `main`, but the object it points to is not destroyed since there's another instance of `shared_ptr` still referring to it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Why is the 'Out of scope' statement not valid for second shared pointer i.e w->mGadget->mWidget?

Comment: Because it's not an object with automatic storage duration. It's a non-static data member, it's created and destroyed together with the object of the class of which it's a member. Consider: `Widget* p; { p = new Widget; }` You wouldn't expect `p->mGadget` to be destroyed at the closing brace, while `*p` is still alive, would you?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - Is it right to say that second shared pointer never goes out of scope as its sitting on a heap? or is there a better way of understanding this?

Comment: Well, sure, if that helps you. It was not tied to any particular scope to begin with, so there's really nothing to go out of.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing the lifetimes of the `shared_ptr`s with the lifetimes of the objects they refer to.

`std::shared_ptr` maintains a pointer to an object, and associates that pointer with a reference count. `shared_ptr` does not destroy the pointed object until the reference count falls to 0.

- `auto w = std::make_shared<Widget>();`
  This creates a new `Widget` object, and then creates a new `shared_ptr` that points to it, and sets the `shared_ptr`'s reference count to 1.
- `w->mGadget = std::make_shared<Gadget>();`
  This creates a new `Gadget` object, and then creates a new `shared_ptr` that points to it, and sets the `shared_ptr`'s reference count to 1.
- `w->mGadget->mWidget = w;`
  This assigns `w` to the `Gadget` object's `mWidget` member, incrementing the reference count of the `Widget` pointer to 2.

Now, when `main()` exits, the only variable that goes out of scope is `w`, so that is the only variable destroyed, decrementing the reference count of the `Widget` pointer to 1 not 0.  And since there is still an active reference to that pointer, the `Widget` object is not destroyed. And since its `mGadget` member has an active reference to the `Gadget` pointer, the `Gadget` object is not destroyed either.

To solve this, you need to change the `Gadget::mWidget` member to `std::weak_ptr` instead:

```cpp
#include <memory>

struct Gadget;

struct Widget
{
    std::shared_ptr<Gadget> mGadget;
};

struct Gadget
{
    std::weak_ptr<Widget> mWidget; // <-- here
};

int main()
{
    auto w = std::make_shared<Widget>();
    w->mGadget = std::make_shared<Gadget>();
    w->mGadget->mWidget = w;
    return 0;
}
```

`std::weak_ptr` does not increment a `std::shared_ptr`'s reference count (at least until `std::weak_ptr::lock()` is called), so the `Widget` pointer's reference count will be 1 not 2. So when `w` goes out of scope and is destroyed, the reference count of the `Widget` pointer falls to 0, destroying the `Widget` object, which will destroy its `mGadget` member, which will decrement the reference count of the `Gadget` pointer to 0, destroying the `Gadget` object.

Answer (score 2):

There are ***three*** `std::shared_ptr`s here:

1. `w` in `main`
2. `mGadget`
3. `mWidget`

The latter two are members of objects that were created in dynamic scope.

`w` goes out of scope in `main()`, as any other automatically-scoped object. But `mGadget` and `mWidget` are left, each referencing the other's object. These two objects were created in ***dynamic*** scope.

This circular reference prevents either object's last reference from going out of scope and getting destroyed. A mutually-assured stalemate.

Comment: Lets say if 'w' was being pointed to by some completely independent heap constructed Gadget which doesn't get freed then will we see the same issue?

Comment: `w` is an object in automatic scope, that's referencing some object. It doesn't matter who else is referencing the same object. Two objects here are referencing each other. The End.

Comment: Why would I downvote a question I believe is worthy of an answer?

Comment: ok. Not sure why someone just downvoted. Probably someone thinks this question isnt worth asking.

Comment: Unfortunately, an overwhelming majority of questions asked on Stackoverflow are of very poor quality. About 90% of the questions here are from people who are looking for pleasedomyhomeworkforme.com or pleasewritemycodeforme.com. And sometimes people downvote out of habit. I don't think this question should be downvoted, so I acted accordingly.